# What is the difference between pip install and pip download?

Tags: pip

What is the difference between pip install and pip download?

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\nahawk\python\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I did a [diff on the help for the 2 commands](https://www.diffchecker.com/Vz0O5umw) and it wasn't very helpful.  Unfortunately, the options are listed in a little different order, which makes them look more different that they actually are.

```
pip help download
pip help install
```

Comment: FWIW, I had the same results with pip3 -> https://www.diffchecker.com/fAaI8hnr

Comment: `install` includes the last version of `--download` before the schizos developing pip changed it to `download`. I would expect more constant pointless breakage if I were you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in the [online docs for pip download](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/#overview).

IMO, some of this should be stated in the help (i.e. in the description). Otherwise, how would one know how to use it, using `pip help download`?

> pip download replaces the --download option to pip install, which is
>   now deprecated and will be removed in pip 10.
>
> pip download does the same resolution and downloading as pip install,
>   but instead of installing the dependencies, it collects the downloaded
>   distributions into the directory provided (defaulting to the current
>   directory). This directory can later be passed as the value to pip
>   install --find-links to facilitate offline or locked down package
>   installation.
>
> pip download with the --platform, --python-version, --implementation,
>   and --abi options provides the ability to fetch dependencies for an
>   interpreter and system other than the ones that pip is running on.
>   --only-binary=:all: is required when using any of these options. It is important to note that these options all default to the current
>   system/interpreter, and not to the most restrictive constraints (e.g.
>   platform any, abi none, etc). To avoid fetching dependencies that
>   happen to match the constraint of the current interpreter (but not
>   your target one), it is recommended to specify all of these options if
>   you are specifying one of them. Generic dependencies (e.g. universal
>   wheels, or dependencies with no platform, abi, or implementation
>   constraints) will still match an over- constrained download
>   requirement.